# NSURLConnection Delegate not working properly in one situation

Tags: ios, multithreading, delegates, nsurlconnection, alassetslibrary

I've read lots of posts regarding this problem but I couldn't get the callback delegate to work...

I've read that delegate cannot be in a background Thread or it won't get called. I think that this may be the issue... but... well let me put some code here to explain better my problem and see what you guys think.

in main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                    @try {
                        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                        [assetLibrary assetForURL:[object valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
                         {
                             ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                             Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
                             NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
                             NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];//this is NSData may be what you want
                             //[data writeToFile:photoFile atomically:YES];//you can save image later
                             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                             CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
                             CGFloat maxCompression = 0.5f;
                             int maxFileSize = 1280*720; //ou usar 40960 = 40MB ?

                             NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);

                             while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
                             {
                                 compression -= 0.1;
                                 imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);
                             }

                             NSString *guid = [self.idMediasAvailable lastObject];
                             //NSString *guid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
                             NSString *boundary = @"-endUploadBoundary-";
                             NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

                             [client addBlobToContainer:[container objectAtIndex:self.mycontainerIndex] blobName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", guid] contentData:imageData contentType:contentType ];

                             [uploadedMediaID setObject:object forKey:guid];
                             [confirmMedias addObject:guid];
                             [listUploadedMedias addObject:object];
                             [self.idMediasAvailable removeLastObject];

                             //             [allUploadedLock lock];
                             //             [allUploadedLock unlockWithCondition:0];
                         }
                                     failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
                                         NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
                                         [allUploadedLock lock];
                                         [allUploadedLock unlockWithCondition:0];
                                     }];

                    }
                    @catch (NSException *exception) {
                        NSLog(@"Error uploadMedia: %@",[object valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]);
                    }
                });

                [allUploadedLock lockWhenCondition:0];
                [allUploadedLock unlock];
```

this is the addToBlobContainer selector:

```
- (void)addBlobToContainer:(BlobContainer *)container blobName:(NSString *)blobName contentData:(NSData *)contentData contentType:(NSString*)contentType withBlock:(void (^)(NSError*))block
{
CloudURLRequest* request = nil;

if(_credential.usesProxy)
{
    request = [_credential authenticatedRequestWithEndpoint:@"/SharedAccessSignatureService/blob" forStorageType:@"blob" httpMethod:@"PUT" contentData:contentData contentType:contentType, @"x-ms-blob-type", @"BlockBlob", nil];
}
else
{
    NSString* containerName = [container.name lowercaseString];
    NSString* endpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@", [containerName URLEncode], [blobName URLEncode]];
    request = [_credential authenticatedRequestWithEndpoint:endpoint forStorageType:@"blob" httpMethod:@"PUT" contentData:contentData contentType:contentType, @"x-ms-blob-type", @"BlockBlob", nil];
}

[request fetchNoResponseWithBlock:^(NSError* error)
 {
     if(error)
     {
         if(block)
         {
             block(error);
         }
         else if([(NSObject*)_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(storageClient:didFailRequest:withError:)])
         {
             [_delegate storageClient:self didFailRequest:request withError:error];
         }
         return;
     }

     if(block)
     {
         block(nil);
     }
     else if([(NSObject*)_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(storageClient:didAddBlobToContainer:blobName:)])
     {
         [_delegate storageClient:self didAddBlobToContainer:container blobName:blobName];
     }
 }];
```

}

no breakpoint is hit inside the block [request fetchNoResponseWithBlock:ˆ(NSError *error) ...];

and this is the fetchNoResponseWithBlock:ˆ selector:

```
- (void) fetchNoResponseWithBlock:(noResponseBlock)block {
    _noResponseBlock = [block copy];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:self delegate:self];
}
```

and in this same file I have the delegate selectors

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

and none of these are hit as well... btw the interface declaration is @interface CloudURLRequest : NSMutableURLRequest

Ok now the strange thing is that the breakpoints inside the delegate selectors 
are hit when the page is opened and another request is made to get the Blob Containers... but when I try to send a file the file is sent and there is no callback! (I manually check the blob and it uploaded successfully)

I think that when I do this:
    `[assetLibrary assetForURL:[object valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {`

is this block running on a background thread by any chance? or Any suggestions?

I do need the callback to work because I have to unlock a NSLock only when the file completes the upload.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I know this is a huge post. But don`t bother now trying to find a solution for this. I found a workaround.